# How to add a sort condition to a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe like that

```
+-------------------+----+
|DATE               |CODE|
+-------------------+----+
|2015/02/30-14:32:32|xv  |
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val2|
|2016/02/30-07:45:26|cv  |
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val3|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val3|
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val1|
|2015/11/30-04:45:19|sd  |
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val2|
|2016/09/30-14:45:58|cv  |
|2015/08/30-15:45:00|rt  |
|2016/01/30-10:35:31|cv  |
|2016/06/30-20:35:30|xv  |
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val1|
|2016/07/19-22:05:48|rt  |
+-------------------+----+
```

I use this code to sort by date my exemple

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("2015/02/30-14:32:32", "xv"),
  ("2016/02/30-12:50:11", "val2"),
  ("2016/02/30-12:50:11", "val2"),
  ("2016/02/30-12:50:11", "val2"),
  ("2015/01/30-10:45:16", "val2"),
  ("2016/02/30-07:45:26", "cv"),
  ("2016/02/30-12:50:11", "val1"),
  ("2016/02/30-12:50:11", "val1"),
  ("2016/02/30-12:50:11", "val1"),
  ("2016/02/30-12:50:11", "val3"),
  ("2015/01/30-10:45:16", "val3"),
  ("2015/11/30-04:45:19", "sd"),
  ("2015/05/23-10:32:16", "val2"),
  ("2016/09/30-14:45:58", "cv"),
  ("2015/08/30-15:45:00", "rt"),
  ("2016/01/30-10:35:31", "cv"),
  ("2016/06/30-20:35:30", "xv"),
  ("2015/05/23-10:32:16", "val1"),
  ("2016/07/19-22:05:48", "rt")
)).toDF("DATE", "CODE")

val df_sorted = df.sort("DATE")

df_sorted show false
```

I obtain this result:

```
+-------------------+----+
|DATE               |CODE|
+-------------------+----+
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val3|
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val2|
|2015/02/30-14:32:32|xv  |
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val2|
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val1|
|2015/08/30-15:45:00|rt  |
|2015/11/30-04:45:19|sd  |
|2016/01/30-10:35:31|cv  |
|2016/02/30-07:45:26|cv  |
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val3|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/06/30-20:35:30|xv  |
|2016/07/19-22:05:48|rt  |
|2016/09/30-14:45:58|cv  |
+-------------------+----+
```

I would like to add a sort condition. I want all my code begining by val in this order: val2, val1, val3, if they have the same date YYYY/MM/DD-hh:mm:ss and get this result:

```
+-------------------+----+
|DATE               |CODE|
+-------------------+----+
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val2|
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val1|
|2015/02/30-14:32:32|xv  |
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val2|
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val1|
|2015/08/30-15:45:00|rt  |
|2015/11/30-04:45:19|sd  |
|2016/01/30-10:35:31|cv  |
|2016/02/30-07:45:26|cv  |
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val3|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val3|
|2016/06/30-20:35:30|xv  |
|2016/07/19-22:05:48|rt  |
|2016/09/30-14:45:58|cv  |
+-------------------+----+
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sc in a hiveContext, if not wrap sparkContext in a hive context first.

```
df.registerTempTable("MY_TEMP_TABLE);

val sortedDF = sc.sql("SELECT * FROM MY_TEMP_TABLE ORDER BY DATE ASC, CODE DESC");
sortedDF.show
```

Or whatever version of SQL sorting you want to run.

Comment: I had to get my exemple more complex to expose my problem. I had a val3 code to precise that my sort c'ant be only desc or asc

Comment: @a.moussa , I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but it sounds ridiculous. Do one thing, create an extra column, assign numerical value to each value in whatever order you want than sort on new column? Eg, every val2 column's corresponding new column 1, each val1 column's corresponding new column 2, val 3 -> 3. And so on so forth. Than sort on new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by multiple columns:

```
 val df_sorted2 = df.sort("DATE","CODE")
 df_sorted2.show()
```

which gives me:

```
+-------------------+----+
|               DATE|CODE|
+-------------------+----+
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val1|
|2015/01/30-10:45:16|val2|
|2015/02/30-14:32:32|  xv|
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val1|
|2015/05/23-10:32:16|val2|
|2015/08/30-15:45:00|  rt|
|2015/11/30-04:45:19|  sd|
|2016/01/30-10:35:31|  cv|
|2016/02/30-07:45:26|  cv|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val1|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/02/30-12:50:11|val2|
|2016/06/30-20:35:30|  xv|
|2016/07/19-22:05:48|  rt|
|2016/09/30-14:45:58|  cv|
+-------------------+----+
```

Comment: I re-edit my question. I want my sort to be more configurable. i correct my question saying I want val2 before val1

Comment: So the only thing missing is the order? you can set whether the "code" column is ascending or descending. Is this what you are missing?

Comment: I had to get my exemple more complex to expose my problem. I had a val3 code to precise that my sort c'ant be only desc or asc